# (Google Sheets/Google Forms) I'd like to be able to collect live data from different columns and have them populate one column instead

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I'm collecting data from a Google Form that allows the user to choose which language they'd like the survey to be in, and based on his/her answer, the Google Form will utilize branching to lead them to the questions in the language he/she chose. For example, if they choose 'English,' a question they will answer is 'Full Name,' while if they choose 'Español,' they will answer 'Nombre y apellido.'

This leads the spreadsheet to collect the data from those questions into two separate columns. Is there a way to set up the spreadsheet so it organizes the data from the same translated questions into columns? The form will be receiving data constantly. I've tried stacking the columns using this formula template: ={A2:A5;D2:D5}, but the formula simply moved cells whenever data was added from the Google Form. I am collecting multiple points of data in 6 different languages, and I'm really hoping there's a way to organize this data to make it much less cumbersome to wade through.

If you have any ideas, please let me know! I'll try whatever you've got.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can union the column values, using open ranges, and then filter out the empty values using `=QUERY()` or `=FILTER()`.

This way you'll be effectively joining values from different columns as one.

For example if you wanted to join data of columns A, D and E, you could do:

#### Using QUERY

```
=QUERY({A2:A;D2:D;E2:E}, "select Col1 where Col1 is not null")
```

#### Using FILTER

```
=FILTER({A2:A;B2:B;E2:E}, {A2:A;B2:B;E2:E} <> "")
```

Comment: Just tried this, and it worked! Thank you SO much! 

Comment: Glad to hear that! If you don't mind accepting the answer/upvoting, it will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I just accepted your answer, but I'm unable to upvote it because I'm brand new to the forum. Sorry about that! Thanks again for your help -- you rock!

Comment: Oh, no problem then! Glad to help :)